# Query parameter route constraints

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I just started using ASP.NET Web API 2.1 and have encountered a limitation. Using Attribute Routing, I can do the following:

```
[Route("item/{id:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetItem(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

The URL `/item/5` will be routed to this action, but the URL `/item/abc` will not, because of the `int` constraint in `{id:int}`.

I tried changing my URL so that the `id` parameter was in the query string along with its constraint, despite the use of route constraints on query parameters never being mentioned or demonstrated in the documentation.

```
[Route("item?{id:int}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetItem(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

If I try to run now, I get an error on the `Configure` method call in `Application_Start`.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

The message is as follows.

> ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
>
> The route template cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.

Two things bother me about this.

First, [the section documenting Route Prefixes](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes) on MSDN makes clear that placing a `~` character at the start of the route template is completely acceptable. I tried it, and it works as documented.

Second, if not like this, how can I place a route constraint on a query parameter? Consider the following, with the route constraint removed.

```
[Route("item")]
public IHttpActionResult GetItem(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

The URL `/item/5` will be routed to this action, with `id` set to `5` - but so will the URL `/item/abc`, with `id` set to `0`.

Is there no way to place a route constraint on a query parameter?

Comment: I havent tried, but regular expressions. I used this article: http://feedproxy.google.com/~r/TypeCastException/~3/0OVZG5c2bY0/#Regular-Expressions-in-Route-Constraints and it looks like it allows constrains.

Comment: @celerno Thanks, but that's for MVC, not Web API.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [http://attributerouting.net/#asp-net-web-api](https://web.archive.org/web/20131109124834/http://attributerouting.net/) <sup>**(†)**</sup>, this is not possible:

> "**Beware!** Due to integration issues with the Web API WebHost framework, the following features will not work: …
>
> - querystring parameter constraints, …"

---

<sup>**†)**</sup> Note that this answer was written for a previous version of Web API where attribute routing was done using a separate [`AttributeRouting.WebApi` NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AttributeRouting.WebApi/). Attribute routing has since been [incorporated into the Web API core](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints). Nevertheless, it appears that constraints on query string parameters are still not supported out of the box.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the non-helping answer, would be a quite way of defining it.

Comment: Yes, guess Microsoft took over the project and didn't want the seperate domain. I think you can find most about attribute routing here today: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2