# Web API 2 Routing based on Parameter's Value

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to setup Web Api 2 route based on a parameter's value in the query string.

I have the following requirement:

/api/controller?data=param.data1
should go to controller's action 1

/api/controller?data=param.data2
should go to controller's action 2
any other value of data must go to action 3.

I know there's an option to set a constraint with a regex, but the examples I've found are for generic scenarios and not as specific as mine.

This is what I've tried

```
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "test",
        routeTemplate: "api/Hub/{data2}",
        defaults: new { action = "Test" },
        constraints: new  { data2 = @"^(param\.data2)$" }

    );
```

Is there a way to do it? Maybe there's a better way?

Important to note, I cannot change the URI of the service. It must have ?data=[value]
This is a fallback for a legacy system :(

Comment: Roman, were you able to get this working? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589011/query-parameter-route-constraints#21589217 suggests it actually isn't possible, but the page it references ( http://attributerouting.net/#asp-net-web-api ) has been offline for a few days now, so I haven't been able to read the context myself.  I did try djikay's suggestion below, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @shanon unfortunately djikay's suggestion didn't work for me too. I ended up writing a controller that accepts all requests, and then dispatches them to proper actions based on the value in ?data=. It's an ugly switch{} but it was the only way I could think of at the time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **Attribute Routing**, new in Web API 2.

Let's say you have the following actions, where the `data` param is, let's say, a string:

```
public Stuff GetStuffForData1(string data) { ... }

public Stuff GetStuffForData2(string data) { ... }

public Stuff GetStuffForData(string data) { ... }
```

Since you mentioned `regex`, you can specify route constraints for each of the above actions using a regex like the one you mentioned in your question<sup>1</sup>, for example:

```
[Route("controller/{data:regex(@"^(param\.data1)$")]
public Stuff GetStuffForData1(string data) { ... }

[Route("controller/{data:regex(@"^(param\.data2)$")]
public Stuff GetStuffForData2(string data) { ... }

// No need for a route constraint for other data params.
public Stuff GetStuffForData(string data) { ... }
```

The general syntax is `{parameterName:constraint(params)}` (`params` is optional and is not used for all constraints). In the above example, the first route will only be selected if the `data` segment of the URI matches the *data1* regex. Similarly, the second route will be selected if the `data` segment of the URI matches the *data2* regex. Otherwise, the last route will be chosen.

In general, the total ordering is determined as follows:

1. Compare the `RouteOrder` property of the route attribute. Lower values are evaluated first. The default order value is zero.
2. Look at each URI segment in the route template. For each segment, order as follows:

   1. Literal segments.
   2. Route parameters with constraints.
   3. Route parameters without constraints.
   4. Wildcard parameter segments with constraints.
   5. Wildcard parameter segments without constraints.
3. In the case of a tie, routes are ordered by a case-insensitive ordinal string comparison (`OrdinalIgnoreCase`) of the route template.

You can even create your own custom route constraints by implementing the `IHttpRouteConstraint` interface and registering it in the `Register` method of your `WebApiConfig` class, assuming you're hosting on IIS, or in the `Configuration` method of your `Startup` class if self-hosting using OWIN.

Note I haven't personally tried any of the above, but it should all work; at the very least it should give you some ideas. For more details, including very nice examples, you should start by taking a look at the following article (which I shamelessly used extensively in my answer):

- http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#constraints

<sup>1</sup> I'm really not an expert on writing regexes, so unfortunately I can't advise you on the specific ones you'll need.