# Differentiate routes by the querystring

Tags: c#, .net, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I need to be able to have the same route to get two different kinds of output.

```
/api/v1/items?ids=1,2,3
```

should retrieve the list of items containing those three entries, however

```
/api/v1/items?from=142523&limit=4
```

should retrieve a cursor paginated response, where `from` would be the id of the item.

I know that in the past it was possible to create route constraints based on querystring, but that has been removed according to the answer posted here:
 [Query parameter route constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589011/query-parameter-route-constraints)

What would be the best way to tackle this? Attribute routing is a no-go, as we don't want to have a `items/{list-of-ids}` routes in the application. I could merge the methods into one with optional parameters, but then the API output is inconsistent in the automatically generated documentation (paginated vs non-paginated response). Is it possible to achieve what I want using custom route constraints?

Comment: I wouldn't say you get two different kinds of output, rather you get the same kind, just different representations of a larger collection. Also consider that you might like to have a limit on a non-filtered request, such that you don't return _all_ of the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Optional Parameter` to define your API endpoint like below. Your query string values will automatically get parameter binded if you keep the parameter name same and don't have to define separate route for them

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult items(string ids, int from = 0, int limit = 0)
{
  //code here
}
```

Comment: I actually need to keep those two methods separate, as they have an output type defined (a custom PaginatedResponse and just a list of items), that is then visible in the Swagger API documentation.

Comment: Why not just return a list of items in both case? As long as filters exist such that the client can paginate, why does the server need to deal with it? For example, `items?take=10`, then `items?skip=10&take10` which can then nicely map to LINQ, and `IQueryable<T>` if need be

Comment: It's not something I have any control over.  The API uses the same wrapper class as a response to all requests that include pagination. The API consumers expect it and I can't remove/change it. I actually need to create another method and have a separate routing for it, so that it's visible in the generated documentation as a completely different request with a differently structured json output, based on the query string constraint, which no longer exist in webAPI2.

Comment: In the end, after some hours spent researching, it looks like it's not possible to recreate the querystring constraint easily and in a relatively sane way, so we did combine the methods into one and create a fake paginated output class. Not perfect, but it seems that there's no better way at the moment.